# How to make a glyphicon work as a submit button?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, input, glyphicons

I have a button of type `Submit` with text as `edit` for POST method in asp.net HTML.BeginForm.I want to replace it with a `glyphicon-edit`.How to achieve the same functionality as `input`.I am able to achieve the functionality using Edit button.I want the same functionality using `glyphicon-edit`

**HTML**

```
<br />

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Editing" value="Edit" />

<div class="circle">
  <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></div>
</div>
```

CSS and Look of `glyphicon-edit` is included in a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/DTcHh/14991/)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can write a button with a type `submit` and wrap an glyphicon inside

```
<button type="submit">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
</button>
```

**Edit :**

- The button style will applied to glyphicon, but you can remote the default button css properties (for eg. `background:none;border:none;padding:0;`) and apply new style
- onclick border appears ? - `outline:none` should solve the outline border issue onclick.

Comment: if i use this,the styles of button will be applied,i don't want that.See my fiddle.

Comment: @IamRaviteja you can always overwrite/nullify the default button css property. (For eg. `background:none; border:none;padding:0;`) background color, border,padding are just the default property of button

Comment: does `outline:none;` would solve the outline border issue onclick. i couldn't see the border on mine.

Answer (score 7):

Use above html and css:

Html:

```
<div class="circle">
   <button type="submit" class="submit-with-icon">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
   </button>
</div>
```

Css :

```
.circle {
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 0.25em solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-edit{
  font-size:28px;
  padding: 8px 3px 0 8px;
}

.submit-with-icon {
  background: transparent;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
}

.circle:active {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
  border-color: rgb(173, 173, 173);
}
```

I've added one class named `submit-with-icon` in which I'm removing border and making background transparent.

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15000/).

Comment: border is appearing on clicking

Comment: I've update my answer and fiddle. Add outline: 0; in submit-with-icon class, It will remove on-click border.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, there is no need to use other elements. Use a `<button>` element for the submit button, instead of `<input>`, and apply the `glyphicon-edit` class directly to it.

- Style the hover, focus and active states as desired and remove the default focus outline.
- The glyph is vertically centered with `line-height`.

#### Example

```css
.glyphicon.glyphicon-edit {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: none;
  transition: color .3s, background .3s;
  /*box-shadow helps soften the choppy circle*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000, inset 0 0 2px #000;
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-edit:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-edit:focus {
  border-color: blue;
  outline: none;
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-edit:active {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/DTcHh/14991/netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<button class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" name="Editing" value="Edit"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 0.25em solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-edit {
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 8px 0 0 3px;
}
.circle button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="circle">
  <button type="submit">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: on click border is appearing

Comment: @IamRaviteja Updated it. adding " outline: none " to the button will solve this problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

`<button class="btn btn-secondary-outline glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="submit">`